# Как заменить указатель на переопределенный (виртуальный) метод на указатель своего метода?

Tags: c#

Приведу код:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void test()
    {

    }
}

public class Target : Base
{
    public override void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Target.test()");
    }

    public void test3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Target.test3()");
    }
}

public class Target2
{
    public void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Target.test2()");
    }
}

public class Injection
{
    public static void replace()
    {
        MethodInfo methodToReplace = typeof(Target).GetMethod("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        MethodInfo methodToInject = typeof(Target2).GetMethod("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToReplace.MethodHandle);
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle);
        ReplaceInner(methodToReplace, methodToInject);
    }

    static void ReplaceInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            {
                int* inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer();
                int* tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer();
                *tar = *inj;
            }
            else
            {
                ulong* inj = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
                ulong* tar = (ulong*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
                *tar = *inj;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Injection.replace();
        Target target = new Target();
        target.test();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

При замене указателя не переопределенного (не виртуального) метода все работает, т.е. вместо метода test() класса Target, вызывается метод test() класса Target2. В случае с заменой указателя виртуального метода вызывается тот же переопределенный метод.

Иными словами, если заменить указатель например метода test3() из класса Target на указатель метода test() из класса Target2, то при вызове target.test() вызывается метод test() из класса Target2. Но с виртуальными методами такое не срабатывает.

Comment: можно попробовать менять адрес базового метода

Comment: Вы делаете какой-то совершенно странный и очень грубый хак. Если вы такое пытаетесь сделать, вы должны очень чётко и хорошо знать, что вы делаете и почему, и не спрашивать о помощи. В хорошем коде подобных конструкций быть не должно.

Comment: VladD, мне нужно объяснить зачем мне это нужно? Звучит как обвинение.

Comment: Оптимизатор имеет право заинлайнить функцию — _where is your god now?_

Comment: Пример взят http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method    Никаких инъекций из одного  процесса в чужой не осуществляется. Поэтому речи о каком-то взломе быть не может. Все делается исключительно в мирных целях, а именно создать оболочку для каждого метода в котором будет осуществляться вызов метода оригинала. По аналогии с работой профайлера.

Comment: Вы выбрали из всех возможных путей самый плохой. Надеяться на то, что указатели на функции находятся в заранее известных местах, неправильно, и хуже того, не работает. Используйте [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) лучше.

Comment: чет плохо продолжать работать через Reflection, зачем указатели....

Comment: VladD, полагаю, Вы прекрасно знали о минусе использования библиотеки "Mono.Cecil" - модификация сборок приведет к сбросу подписи. Аналогично использованию «ilasm.exe» и «ildasm.exe». По определению, это и есть взлом.
Что касается "самого плохого" - это спорное утверждение. Данный метод прекрасен, тем что позволяет осуществлять замену указателей в «runtime» режиме, и после перезапуска не оставит никаких следов.
В моем случае это подходит как нельзя лучше. Объясню почему, на стороне пользователя наш комплекс нельзя перезаписывать или не запланировано прерывать его работу.

Comment: Самый тонкий способ - это включить режим сбора статистики во время работы, находясь внутри процесса и консолидировать всю информацию об узких местах ПО. Конечно же,  можно было заранее об этом побеспокоится - встроить в методы атрибуты или вручную прописать некие флаги в каждую функцию, но этот вариант более затратный.
По поводу «заранее известных мест» - работа в упомянутом выше режиме позволяет у всех, загрузившихся сборок извлечь сформировавшийся указатель в памяти на все методы, возвращая «MethodHandle» получается что, мы берем его из заранее известного места в пределах работы комплекса.

Comment: Большего и не требуется, за исключением виртуальных методов. Вызов же виртуальных методов реализуется при помощи механизма позднего связывания, думаю, Вы хорошо знакомы с его работой. Указатель в момент выполнения, а это значит когда создается конкретный экземпляр класса и вызывается конкретное переопределение или сам виртуальный метод, берется ссылка на тип созданного объекта, и вызывается его переопределенный метод либо виртуальный. 
Коллега, предлагаю  обойтись без антистрефонов о логике моего мышления и моей наивности. И рано судить о неработоспособности подхода.

Comment: Подход ужасен тем, что он опирается на недокументированные и негарантированные ничем подробности бинарного формата. Эти подробности имеют право поменяться в любой момент, и ваш хак просто в лучшем случае упадёт, а в худшем приведёт к вызову неправильной функции и потере данных.

Comment: О какой цифровой подписи вы говорите, если вы нарушаете безопасность редактированием бинарного кода в памяти? Если вы уж редактируете код в памяти, то зачем вам цифровая подпись на вашем exe? Смысл цифровой подписи как раз в том и состоит, чтобы защитить от редактирования исполняемых файлов.

Comment: Ну откуда вы это берете? "на недокументированные и негарантированные ничем подробности бинарного формата". Рихтер вам в помощь. Даже не хочу вступать в эту бессмысленную дискуссию. Ответ дан, примите как должное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ в англоязычной версии:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782934/how-to-replace-the-pointer-to-the-overridden-virtual-method-in-the-pointer-of

Сборка в Release x86 и x64. Для Debug - необходимо дополнительно учесть смещение.