# Подмена метода во время RunTime

Tags: c#, рефлексия, методы, swap

Чисто спортивного интереса ради появилась задача: во время `RunTime` *подменить* тело одного метода на тело другого. Собственно, задача была успешно, как показалось на первый взгляд, решена таковым образом:

```
public static void Inject(MethodInfo ToReplace, MethodInfo ToInject)
{
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(ToReplace.MethodHandle);
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(ToInject.MethodHandle);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* inject = (byte*)(IntPtr.Size == 4 ? *((int*)ToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2) : *((long*)ToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1));
        byte* target = (byte*)(IntPtr.Size == 4 ? *((int*)ToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2) : *((long*)ToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1));
        int* injectSrc = (int*)(inject + 1);
        int* targetSrc = (int*)(target + 1);
        *targetSrc = (((int)inject + 5) + *injectSrc) - ((int)target + 5);
    }
}
```

Подготавливаю методы для включения в область ограниченного выполнения, а после просто подменяю указатель на тело метода `ToReplace` указателем на тело метода `ToInject`.
Сие прекрасно работает, однако лишь в **Debug**-режиме, когда не применяются никакие оптимизации. Так что мой вопрос такой: какие есть еще способы подмены методов во время исполнения? 
**P.S**. - вопрос чисто для общего развития, а не для каких-то серьезных и надежных вещей, так что самые небезопасные варианты также приветствуются)

Comment: [тут похожий код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/551955/186999), говорит для релиза как раз :-)

Comment: @Grundy однако все же не работает)

Comment: возможно дело в смещениях :)