# Имена переменных и проверка типов во время Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, типы, runtime, имена

Товарищи, возникли некоторые вопросы по поводу `runtime`, связанные с `именами переменных` и `проверкой их типов`, однако для лучшего понимания распишу всю ситуацию.

---

В [одном из моих вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840812/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-runtime) я приводил пример *подмены* методов во время `runtime`. Чуть "поигравшись" с этим, я обнаружил, что ключевое слово `this` в рамках инъецированного метода ссылается именно на тот объект, в класс которого он и был инъецирован. Я решил проверить, будет ли это работать и с переменными
Так что я создал `тестовый класс`:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

И класс для `подмены`:

```
public class InjectorClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void SetterInjecter(int Data)
    {
        Value = ~Data;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from injected setter!");
    }
}
```

Далее я произвел замену:

```
Type testType = typeof(TestClass);
Type injectType = typeof(InjectorClass);
Injector.Inject(testType.GetMethod("set_Value"), injectType.GetMethod("SetterInjecter"));
TestClass test = new TestClass();
test.Value = int.MinValue;
Console.WriteLine("test.Value == {0}", test.Value);
```

И все это действительно сработало, ибо я получил следующий вывод:

> Hello from injected setter! 
>   test.Value == 2147483647

(`~a = -a - 1` => ~int.MinValue = int.MaxValue = `2147483647`)
Тем самым мы убедились, что можем получить доступ к переменной из инъецированного метода по имени

---

После этого я пошел дальше и решил изменить тип переменной `Value` в классе `InjectorClass`, тем самым посмотрев, что получится при присвоении переменной типа `int` значения совершенного иного типа. Для этого я создал такую структуру:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 4)]
public struct IntByte
{
    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public byte _0;
    [FieldOffset(1), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public byte _1;
    [FieldOffset(2), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public byte _2;
    [FieldOffset(3), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public byte _3;

    public IntByte(int From)
    {
        string bits = Convert.ToString(From, 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
        _3 = Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(0, 8), 2);
        _2 = Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(8, 8), 2);
        _1 = Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(16, 8), 2);
        _0 = Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(24, 8), 2);
    }
}
```

Ее суть в том, что в памяти она выглядит ровно как заданный в инициализаторе `int From`. 
Также я чуть изменил `InjectorClass`:

```
public class InjectorClass
{
    public IntByte Value { get; set; }

    public void SetterInjecter(int Data)
    {
        Value = new IntByte(~Data);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from injected setter!\n\nbyte 0: {0};\nbyte 1: {1};\nbyte 2: {2};\nbyte 3: {3};\n\n", Value._0, Value._1, Value._2, Value._3);
    }
}
```

Тем самым получается, что в `runtime` после подмены мы присваиваем переменной типа `int` значение переменной типа `IntByte`. Запустив код вновь (код подмены не менялся с прошлого пункта), я ожидал увидеть крах приложения, сообщение об ошибке или хоть какой сигнализатор того, что я совершаю что-то неправомерное. Однако в консоли я вновь видел вполне себе веселый и бодрый вывод:

> Hello from injected setter!
>  
>   byte 0: 255;
>  
>   byte 1: 255;
>   byte 2: 255;
>  
>   byte 3: 127;
>  
>   test.Value == 2147483647

Такое поведение мне показалось малость странным, ибо я всегда считал, что проверка типов ведется даже в `runtime`, т.к., скажем, такой код:

```
dynamic a = new IntByte(1);
int b = a;
```

Пусть он и скомпилируется, однако все же выбросит ошибку во время выполнения...

---

Едем дальше. Хорошо. Пускай типы уже не проверяются, но если мы, скажем, сошлемся на переменную, которой не существует в текущем экземпляре, ошибка ведь вылетит, правда? Нет. Как ни странно, поменяв `InjectorClass` на это:

```
public class InjectorClass
{
    public IntByte X { get; set; }

    public void SetterInjecter(int Data)
    {
        X = new IntByte(~Data);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from injected setter!\n\nbyte 0: {0};\nbyte 1: {1};\nbyte 2: {2};\nbyte 3: {3};\n\n", X._0, X._1, X._2, X._3);
    }
}
```

Я все равно получил тот же самый вывод:

> Hello from injected setter!
>  
>   byte 0: 255;
>  
>   byte 1: 255;
>   byte 2: 255;
>  
>   byte 3: 127;
>  
>   test.Value == 2147483647

Вот тут я уже впал в окончательную задумчивость, что же там в `runtime` творится.
К слову, если добавить в `InjectorClass` переменную с названием `Value` или типом `int`, то изменение `X` в инъецированном методе перестает влиять на `test.Value`, так что какая-то логика там точно присутствует

---

Собственно, пора бы и резюмировать возникшие у меня вопросы по данному поводу:

1. Почему в указанном примере не ведется проверки типов переменных в `runtime`, если аналогичный по своей сути код с использованием `dynamic` все же падает во время исполнения?
2. Почему свойство экземпляра класса, в который был инъецирован метод, ссылающийся на свойство с другим именем, все же меняет свое значение?
3. Обратив внимание на структуру `IntByte`, вы заметите, что присвоение байтов идет с конца. С последнего к нулевому. То есть последовательность байтов для `int.MaxValue` выглядит как `255 -> 255 -> 255 -> 127`, хотя по логике все должно быть наоборот. С чем связан такой обратный порядок значащих байтов? Сталкивался с этим, когда в памяти обрабатывал изображения в виде массива байтов, однако просто принимал как должное)

Буду очень благодарен за разъяснение этих интересных моментов)

Comment: 1) Проверка типов делается один раз при JIT компиляции. Делать её каждый раз при выполнении слишком дорого. 2) После JIT компиляции поля адресуются по смещению, а не по имени. 3) Такой порядок байт связан с тем, что у Вас little-endian система.

Comment: @PetSerAI С пунктами 1 и 3 я разобрался, спасибо) Однако по поводу пункта 2 все равно не ясно, ибо, как я описал в вопросе, в случае добавления в класс `InjectorClass` свойства `int Value` (которое по смещению в данном классе уедет дальше "родного" `int Value` для `TestClass`), изменение свойства `X`, которое по смещению как раз и должно подходить, перестает влиять на свойство `Value`

Comment: Вы добавляли `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` к `InjectorClass`? Без этого runtime волен располагать поля так, как ему заблагорассудится, а не в том порядке в котором Вы их определили. Также Вы используете не поля, а автоматические свойства. Я не помню, предоставляет ли спецификация C# какие-либо гарантии относительно того в каком порядке поля поддержки для них будут определены.