# Подмена метода C#

Tags: c#

Вопрос не нов, но в сети я не смог найти ответа к сожалению. В общем ситуация следующая,у меня есть класс к примеру:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod");
    }            
}
```

Задача следующая мне нужно подменить метод MyMethod на другой, новый. Причем мне НЕ требуется динамическая подмена методов,мне нужно просто затереть существующий и заменить новым.

Дело в следующем. я пишу дополнение к одной опер сорс программе и для того что бы мое дополнение было легко переносимо на другие более новые версии этой программы (которые разрабатывают другие разработчики независимо от меня) все стыковки с исходным кодом я реализовал как методы расширения. В итоге весь код дополнения которым я занимаюсь легко переносится на новые версии программы путем добавления двух строк в исходный код. В этой программе есть класс в котором содержится метод который мне нужно затереть, соответственно я не хочу влазить в чужой код напрямую что бы сохранить легкость переноса моих дополнений на новые версии программы. Подскажите можно ли это как то реализовать?

Если сделать что то вроде:

```
static class MyClassExtencion
{
    public static new void MyMethod(this MyClass cl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New method");
        cl.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

То это само собой работать не будет, так как метод расширения не затирает изначальный метод... однако хотелось бы сделать как нибудь схожим образом

Comment: Метод виртуальный?

Comment: @tym32167 Нет к сожалению

Comment: Класс используется как класс или как реализация какого то интерфейса? (Я по возможность декоратор написать)

Comment: Как класс исспользуется.

Comment: Там получается так что класс метод которого мне нужно подменить реализован другими разработчиками и используется в их же классах. Но мое дополнение несколько меняет ход выполнения программы и в итоге этот метод ведет не правильные расчеты. Т.е. я не хочу влезать не в объявления этого класса не в область использования данного класса. Мне просто нужно скорректировать этот метод и сделать это не влезая в  код самого класса метод которого я корректирую, т.е. сделать как можно более назевисимую коррекцию чужого кода.

Comment: если разработчиками не заложена возможность подмены этого метода, то вы полюбому куда то да залезете, либо в их исходный код, либо у себя в коде какие то танцы с рефлексией будете проводить

Comment: Использовать Action не судьба? и дописать нужное количество методов.

Comment: @NewView А можно поподробнее про Вашу идею ? предлагаете делегат создать внутри класса и ему передавать требуемый мне метод?

Comment: Примерно так, путей то много, по крайней мере это гибкое решение не требующее рефлексии.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840812/Подмена-метода-во-время-runtime

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight благодарю,попробую покопать в данном направлении